# Changing attr href to something else via jquery. What does it all affect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As mentioned in the title is the question what does this all affect.

The code works fine and you want really see anything happen expect of the "href" attribute from the `<a>` tag gets changed to "iref".

I do this to load the content later via jquery.load()

Should I do this different? What would be the "right" way to do it?
What about google, does it affect google robots? I ask this because: if there is no javascript turned on, the links want change from href to iref and work off course. So the robots can follow them or not?

Thanks for all the answers.

[There is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7PSVR/)

```
<a class="top-nav animMainBox" href="/home.html">Home</a>
<a class="top-nav animMainBox" href="notathome.html">Not at home</a>
<a class="top-nav animMainBox" href="/contact.html">Contact</a>


<style type="text/css">
    a{margin:10px;}
</style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        hrefToIref();

        $(document).on('click','.animMainBox',function(){
            loadNewBox($(this), true);
        });

    });


    function hrefToIref() {
        $('.animMainBox').each(function(){
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            $(this).attr('href','javascript:;').attr('iref',url);
        });
        $('.button').each(function(){
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            $(this).attr('href','javascript:;').attr('iref',url);
        });
    }

    function loadNewBox($this,animate) {
        // loading and returning new boxes via 
        // var url = $this.attr('iref');
        // $(".wrapper").load(url+' .toggle.box',{noncache: new Date().getTime()}, function(response, status, xhr) {}
    }


</script>
```

Comment: @Connor good question. if I translate effect and or affect both seem to be right. So I really don't know which one is better. I thought affect sounds more effectiv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I do this different?

Yes, definitely. `iref` attributes look quite invalid.

> Can robots follow them or not?

Yes, they usually will only look at your static HTML markup with the `href` attributes.

> What about google, does it affect google robots?

Google is a bit different I think as they can view pages with JS turned on. I don't know whether your script will stop them from following the links.

> What would be the "right" way to do it?

Just leave the `href` attributes as they are. Prevent following them when they're clicked.

```
$(document).on('click','.animMainBox, .button', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    loadNewBox($(this), true);
});
function loadNewBox($this,animate) {
    var url = $this.attr('href');
    //                    ^ just use the correct attribute
    …
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('a').click(function(){ return false; });

        $(document).on('click','.animMainBox',function(){
            loadNewBox($(this), true);
        });

    });
```

This will stop the links from working and you can load something later on.
Search robots can still visit the links yes.

Comment: That hardly will work, as `return false` will lead to `stopPropagation()`.

Comment: Well you can add the `load` function in the `$('a').click(function(){ return false; });`.

Comment: Yes, you could. But you're loosing the event delegation with that.